# How to put a random generator in the whole code for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently working on a math game in C# windows form. I have to have generate 2 random numbers 1-99 and display that for each math function. I have two buttons, one to start the game and one to submit the answer. My mistake was I did two separate sets of random numbers making the start button have different random numbers from the submit button. I want to have the same random numbers for each section how do I do that? I have an idea and that is to put it in the public class form1 but it keeps saying I have an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MathLearning
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //This is where I believe it is supposed to go
        //Random ranNum = new Random();
        //int num1 = ranNum.Next(1, 100);
        //int num2 = ranNum.Next(1, 100);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Text = "Next";
            if (rdoAddition.Checked)
            {
                int answer = num1 + num2;
                lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " + " + num2 + "?"}";
            }
            if (rdoSubtraction.Checked)
            {
                int answer = num1 / num2;
                lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " / " + num2 + "?"}";
            }
            if (rdoMultiplication.Checked)
            {
                int answer = num1 * num2;
                lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " * " + num2 + "?"}";
            }
            if (rdoDivison.Checked)
            {
                int answer = num1 / num2;
                lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " / " + num2 + "?"}";
            }
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random ranNum = new Random();
            int num1 = ranNum.Next(1, 100);
            int num2 = ranNum.Next(1, 100);
            int i = 0;
            if(rdoGenderM.Checked)
            {
                if (rdoAddition.Checked)
                {
                    int answer = num1 + num2;
                    if(int.Parse(txtAnswer.Text) == answer)
                    {
                        lblQuestion.Text = $"{"Good Job Sir\nYou got " + i + " correct Out of " + i + " problems."}";
                    }
                    else
                        lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " + " + num2 + "?\nThe answer is " + answer}";
                }
            }
            //else if(rdoGenderF.Checked)
            //{
            //    lblQuestion.Text = $"{"Good Job Madam\nYou got " + i + " correct Out of " + i + " problems."}";
            //}
            //else
            //   lblQuestion.Text = $"{"Good Job Unknown gender\nYou got " + i + " correct Out of " + i + " problems."}";
        }
    }
}
```

[This is what my form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ejh3.png)

Comment: You believe correctly. Drop the code from in `btnSubmit_Click` and put it where you think.

Comment: You also should use `decimal` rather than `int` as with `int` when you do `9 / 2` the answer you get is `4`, not `4.5`. You need `decimal` (or `double`) to get, well, decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, just initialise them in the constructor, or whever it makes sense.

```
private Random ranNum = new Random();
private int num1;
private int num2;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    num1 = ranNum.Next(1, 100);
    num2 = ranNum.Next(1, 100);
}
```

**The longer story**

Field/property initializers cannot access non static members such as your random field, it that were the case it would introduce order dependent initialization logic that is easily breakable and implementation dependent. You can however access instance members in a constructor. At the time a constructor is called, all other field and property initializers have been called which makes it safe to call instance members.

Answer (score -1):

This should work, every time you click start it will generate new numbers.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MathLearning
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //This is where I believe it is supposed to go
        Random ranNum = new Random();
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int numProblems = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Text = "Next";
            int num1 = ranNum.Next(1, 100);
            int num2 = ranNum.Next(1, 100);
            if (rdoAddition.Checked)
            {
                int answer = num1 + num2;
                lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " + " + num2 + "?"}";
            }
            if (rdoSubtraction.Checked)
            {
                int answer = num1 / num2;
                lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " / " + num2 + "?"}";
            }
            if (rdoMultiplication.Checked)
            {
                int answer = num1 * num2;
                lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " * " + num2 + "?"}";
            }
            if (rdoDivison.Checked)
            {
                int answer = num1 / num2;
                lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " / " + num2 + "?"}";
            }

            numProblems++;
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if(rdoGenderM.Checked)
            {
                if (rdoAddition.Checked)
                {
                    int answer = num1 + num2;
                    if(int.Parse(txtAnswer.Text) == answer)
                    {
                        i++;
                        lblQuestion.Text = $"{"Good Job Sir\nYou got " + i + " correct Out of " + numProblems + " problems."}";
                    }
                    else
                        lblQuestion.Text = $"{num1 + " + " + num2 + "?\nThe answer is " + answer}";
                }
            }
            //else if(rdoGenderF.Checked)
            //{
            //    lblQuestion.Text = $"{"Good Job Madam\nYou got " + i + " correct Out of " + numProblems + " problems."}";
            //}
            //else
            //   lblQuestion.Text = $"{"Good Job Unknown gender\nYou got " + i + " correct Out of " + numProblems + " problems."}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is declaring `int answer` in the `btnStart_Click` method. You've done the same. But it doesn't work - if you're going to show all of that code you should make sure it works.